# What is a 'public facing login integration'

Tags: instagram-api

I am trying to appease the Instagram API policy and one of the requirements under their policy for API approval requires your app to:

"Help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and digital media rights: basic, public_content, comments, relationships, likes, follower_list

This use case is meant for products that don't have a public facing login integration, but are gated to brands and advertisers. The product must support either multiple brands and advertisers (e.g. a social media management platform) or multiple users within a single brand or advertiser organization."

I have searched everywhere but can only find reference to the question in the source, so I'll be damned if I can work out what a 'public facing login integration is.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/